# Name the Uninstall Process in the Task Manager Process list

Tags: nsis

When you launch an uninstall.exe written using WriteUninstaller, the uninstall.exe is named in the process list "Au_.exe", or "Bu_.exe" (depending on how many of the exe's you have launched, it will go through the alphabet).

here is my install section code

```
Section "Install"

WriteRegStr HKLM "${regkey}" "Install_Dir" "$INSTDIR"
WriteRegStr HKLM "${uninstkey}" "DisplayName" "${name}"
WriteRegStr HKLM "${uninstkey}" "DisplayIcon" '"$INSTDIR\icon.ico"'
WriteRegStr HKLM "${uninstkey}" "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\${uninstaller}"'

; Remove all application files copied by previous installation
RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"

SetOutPath $INSTDIR

; Include all files from /build directory
File /r "${src}\*"

; Create start menu shortcut
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${name}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${exec}" "" "$INSTDIR\icon.ico"

WriteUninstaller "${uninstaller}"

SectionEnd
```

and the uninstall section is

```
Section "Uninstall"

${nsProcess::FindProcess} "${name}.exe" $R0
${If} $R0 == 0
    ${nsProcess::KillProcess} "${name}.exe" $R0
${EndIf}    
${nsProcess::Unload}

DeleteRegKey HKLM "${uninstkey}"
DeleteRegKey HKLM "${regkey}"

Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\${name}.lnk"
Delete "$DESKTOP\${name}.lnk" 

; Remove whole directory from Program Files
RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"

; Remove also database files generated by your app if user checked this option
${If} $RemoveAppDataCheckbox_State == ${BST_CHECKED}
    SetShellVarContext all
    RMDir /r "${dbFolder}"
${EndIf}

SectionEnd
```

can any one help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution,
when uninstaller is started the nsis copy the uninstaller.exe to temp folder automatically and start uninstalling using this exe thats why its name is au_.exe , eu_.exe etc, here is the fix you have to manually copy your uninstall.exe to temp folder or any folder but temp is preferable, and then run it from there it will take the name of your uninstaller.exe it can be any name which you want, here is the code

```
!define uninstaller "Testuninstaller.exe"

Function un.onInit

${nsProcess::FindProcess} "${uninstaller}" $R4
${If} $R4 <> 0
    CopyFiles /SILENT "$INSTDIR\${uninstaller}" "$temp\${uninstaller}"
    ExecWait '"$temp\${uninstaller}" _?=$INSTDIR'
    Quit
${EndIf}    
${nsProcess::Unload}
FunctionEnd
```

now your name in the process will be Testunistaller.exe

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to customize the name of this uninstaller file but I did change it from `%UNIQUE%u_.exe` to `Un_%UNIQUE%.exe` for the next version of NSIS 3...